# Calling pandas applymap in an external module from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm working in a jupyter notebook to manage some data with pandas dataframes.

I have a dataframe where I want to clean some values. Specifically, some values contains text between brackets {} and I want to remove the part within brackets.

So I did this:
`df = df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(lambda x: re.sub(r'\{.*\}', '', x).strip())`

and it works fine.

Then, because I had other dataframes in other notebooks where I wanted to to the same, I externalized this function in a utils.py module:

```
def clean_dataframe(dataframe: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    dataframe = dataframe.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(r'\{.*\}', '', x).strip())
    # ... some other stuff
    return dataframe
```

In my notebook, I import the function, I use it on my dataframe, and now it doesn't work.

any idea why?

## Method that works

in mynotebook.ipynb:

```
import re
df = df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(lambda x: re.sub(r'\{.*\}', '', x).strip())
df.head()
```

The output shows the values without the part in brackets

## Method that fails

in utils.py

```
def clean_dataframe(dataframe: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    dataframe = dataframe.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(r'\{.*\}', '', x).strip())
    # ... some other stuff
    return dataframe
```

in mynotebook.ipynb:

```
from utils import clean_dataframe
df = clean_dataframe(df)
df.head()
```

Parts in brackets are still there in the output.

In utils.py, I also have another function that prints some of the dataframe values. It works just fine. I also get no errors at all from vscode...

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple minutes after asking the question, I think I found the issue.

I restarted the kernel and it worked fine.

I think at some point I made changes to the external module, where the applymap didn't work, and that ended up in the notebook kernel, which doesn't refresh automatically if you change an external module, apparently.

So I guess you have to restart the kernel if you change something in external modules...